# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: no root <launch> tag

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to launch a file and I am getting this error every time, I was trying to use the turtlebot3 map in my different robot. so I copied turtlebot3_house.world to my robot workspace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <include file="$(find robot)/world/turtlebot3_house.world">
  </include>
  <param name="robot_description" command="cat '$(find robot)/urdf/robot.xacro'"/>

  <arg name="x" default="0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0.5"/>

  <node name="robot_spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen"
      args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z)" />

</launch>
```

my error

```
RLException: while processing /home/guru/first_robot/catkin_ws/src/robot/world/turtlebot3_house.world:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: no root <launch> tag
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

the launch file which command which I used

```
roslaunch robot spawn.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375116/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-no-root-%3Claunch%3E-tag/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2021-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-03-31**:
Can you provide more description:
For example: What command you are running to launch file, the directory structure of your folders, etc.

I think that your launch file is correct, but then also look at this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/257470/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax-no-root-launch-tag/) if this might help you.

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-03-31**:
@ranjit I have just checked that, seems that's not the problem and I have also added command here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is pretty clear:

> ```
> RLException: while processing /home/guru/first_robot/catkin_ws/src/robot/world/turtlebot3_house.world:
> ```

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: no root <launch> tag
```

it states there `is no root <launch> tag in turtlebot3_house.world`, and that's correct.

`turtlebot3_house.world` is a Gazebo `.world` file, not a `.launch` file you can `include` in another `.launch` file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-03-31**:
so, how can i make it a launch file

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-31**:
You can't. That's not how this works.

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-03-31**:
thanks, i got that

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-31**:
[This tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch) explains how to use a Gazebo world in a launch file.